# Mocking up static methods in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am having trouble mocking up a static method in jest. Immagine you have a class A with a static method:

```
export default class A {
  f() {
    return 'a.f()'
  }

  static staticF () {
    return 'A.staticF()'
  }
}
```

And a class B that imports A

```
import A from './a'

export default class B {
  g() {
    const a = new A()
    return a.f()  
  }

  gCallsStaticF() {
    return A.staticF()
  }
}
```

Now you want to mock up A. It is easy to mock up f():

```
import A from '../src/a'
import B from '../src/b'

jest.mock('../src/a', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { f: () => { return 'mockedA.f()'} }
  })
})

describe('Wallet', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const b = new B()
    const result = b.g()
    console.log(result) // prints 'mockedA.f()'
  })
})
```

However, I could not find any documentation on how to mock up A.staticF. Is this possible?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can just assign the mock to the static method

```js
import A from '../src/a'
import B from '../src/b'

jest.mock('../src/a')

describe('Wallet', () => {
    it('should work', () => {
        const mockStaticF = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('worked')

        A.staticF = mockStaticF

        const b = new B()

        const result = b.gCallsStaticF()
        expect(result).toEqual('worked')
    })
})
```

Comment: And then you can also do `expect(mockStaticF).toBeCalled()` type assertions, though the bound version won't work (e.g. `expect(A.staticF).toBeCalled()` would throw)

Comment: Why use bind in this case? Could it not be simpler just to assign `mockStaticF` to `A.staticF`? e.g. `A.staticF = mockStaticF`

Comment: can also mock 'staticF' outside 'describe', eg 
`jest.mock('../src/a', () => {
  const A = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    f: () => { return 'mockedA.f()'} }
  });
  A.staticF = jest.fn();
  return A;
})`

Comment: when you need mocking static fn only once, you can adjust this solution a bit:
`const mockStaticF = jest.fn(A.staticF).mockImplementationOnce(...); A.staticF = mockStaticF;`

Comment: There are two problems here that don't take how Jest works into account. Never mock methods with assignment like `A.staticF = mockStaticF` if you can't avoid this, this prevents Jest from restoring methods where necessary and potentially results in test cross-contamination, this is what jest.spyOn is for. `jest.mock('../src/a')` does an auto-mock, it already makes static method a stub that allows for  `A.staticF.mockReturnValue('worked')`.

Comment: will this work?  `expect(mockStaticF).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter It worked for me. I wanted to mock static method 'register' of class Chart 
Chart.register = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {}

Answer (score 21):

Hope this will help you

```
// code to mock
export class AnalyticsUtil {
    static trackEvent(name) {
        console.log(name)
    }
}

// mock
jest.mock('../src/AnalyticsUtil', () => ({
    AnalyticsUtil: {
        trackEvent: jest.fn()
    }
}))
```

```
// code to mock
export default class Manager {
    private static obj: Manager
    
    static shared() {
        if (Manager.obj == null) {
            Manager.obj = new Manager()
        }
        return Manager.obj
    }
    
    nonStaticFunc() {
    }
}

// mock
jest.mock('../src/Manager', () => ({
    shared: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        nonStaticFunc: jest.fn()
    })
}))
```

```
// usage in code
someFunc() {
    RNDefaultPreference.set('key', 'value')
}

// mock RNDefaultPreference
jest.mock('react-native-default-preference', () => ({
    set: jest.fn()
}))
```

```
// code to mock
export namespace NavigationActions {
    export function navigate(
      options: NavigationNavigateActionPayload
    ): NavigationNavigateAction;
}

// mock
jest.mock('react-navigation', () => ({
    NavigationActions: {
        navigate: jest.fn()
    }
}))
```

Comment: Very useful snippets! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I managed to mock it in a separate file in the `__mocks__` folder using prototyping. So you would do:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.f = function() {
    return 'a.f()';
};
A.staticF = function() {
    return 'A.staticF()';
};
export default A;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example with an ES6 import.

```
import { MyClass } from '../utils/my-class';
const myMethodSpy = jest.spyOn(MyClass, 'foo');

describe('Example', () => {
    it('should work', () => {
        MyClass.foo();
        expect(myMethodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to create a mock and give visibility for the mocked method to the test suite. Below full solution with comments.

```js
let mockF; // here we make variable in the scope we have tests
jest.mock('path/to/StaticClass', () => {
  mockF = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()); // here we assign it
  return {staticMethodWeWantToMock: mockF}; // here we use it in our mocked class
});

// test
describe('Test description', () => {
  it('here our class will work', () => {
    ourTestedFunctionWhichUsesThisMethod();
    expect(mockF).toHaveBeenCalled(); // here we should be ok
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### Jest Spies

I went with the route of using `jest.spyOn`.

### Example

#### `encryption.ts`

```
export class Encryption {
  static encrypt(str: string): string {
     // ...
  }

  static decrypt(str: string): string {
    // ...
  }
}
```

#### `property-encryption.spec.ts`

```
import { Encryption } from './encryption'
import { PropertyEncryption } from './property-encryption'

describe('PropertyEncryption', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest
      .spyOn(Encryption, 'encrypt')
      .mockImplementation(() => 'SECRET')
    jest
      .spyOn(Encryption, 'decrypt')
      .mockImplementation(() => 'No longer a secret')
  })

  it("encrypts object values and retains the keys", () => {
    const encrypted = PropertyEncryption.encrypt({ hello: 'world' });

    expect(encrypted).toEqual({ hello: 'SECRET' });
  });

  it("decrypts object values", () => {
    const decrypted = PropertyEncryption.decrypt({ hello: "SECRET" });

    expect(decrypted).toEqual({ hello: 'No longer a secret' });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Object.assign` on the mock constructor allows simultaneous mocking of the class and its static methods. Doing this allows you to achieve the same structure you get when creating a class with static members.

```js
    import A from '../src/a'
    import B from '../src/b'


    jest.mock('../src/a', () =>
      Object.assign(
        jest.fn(
          // constructor
          () => ({
            // mock instance here
            f: jest.fn()
          })),
        { 
         // mock static here
          staticF: jest.fn(),
        }
      )
    )
```