# How check if static methods is called in Jest?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have ES-6 class which is having static methods. How to mock them in Jest to test if they gets called?

I have 3 files

1. Logger

```js
class Logger {
  static log = (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
export default Logger;
```

2. action

```js
// import Logger './Logger';
export const myAction = () => {
  handleRequest(params).then((response) => {
    // Statements
  }).catch((err) => {
    Logger.log(err);
  });
};
```

3. Test file

```js
// import {myAction} from './action';
// import Logger './Logger';
it('should call Logger', () => {
  Logger.log = jest.fn();
  return myAction().then(() => {
    expect(Logger.log).toHaveBeenCalled(); // It is failing
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking up static methods in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421732/mocking-up-static-methods-in-jest)

Comment: That's not helping in my scenario. I updated post with more details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

```
import Logger './Logger';
import {myAction} from './action';

it('should call Logger', async () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Logger, "log");
  await myAction();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

or

```
import Logger './Logger';
import {myAction} from './action';

it('should call Logger', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Logger, "log");
  return myAction().finally(() => {
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just modify the class before creating the instance.

```
const foo = jest.fn()
const bar = jest.fn()

MyClass.foo = foo
MyClass.bar = bar

const myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.foo()

expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

If this is the right approach depends on the way to are testing `MyClass`

edit: I honestly think @lissettdm answer is a better way of doing it