# How do I mock static fields with Jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a client class that imports a separate class and uses static fields from that class in several functions. When I attempt to mock the imported class, the static fields are undefined.

The project is set up as so:

The client class which I want to test is set up

```
import { RealClass } from 'module'
export class Client {
  private containedClass: RealClass

  constructor() {
    this.containedClass = new RealClass();
  }

  funcToTest() {
    if(this.containedClass.somePublicField === RealClass.StaticReadonlyField) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

The real class is a node module with an index.d.ts that looks like

```
declare class RealClass extends SomeOtherRealClass {
    static readonly StaticReadonlyField: 0;
    static readonly StaticReadonlyField1: 1;

    readonly somePublicField;

    //rest of declaration

}
```

I'm attempting to mock the class constructor of `RealClass` such that I can continue to use the functionality of `SomeOtherRealClass in my test, like so:

```
class MockClass extends SomeOtherRealClass {
  static readonly StaticReadonlyField: 0;

  somePublicField = MockClass.StaticReadonlyField;

  //...
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

jest.mock('RealModule', () => {
  return {
    RealClass: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return new MockClass();
    });
  }
});
```

I have a test that manually sets `somePublicField` so that I can properly test my function, however the static field is undefined in the context of the client class:

```
  it('should set public field correctly', () => {
    const classToTest = new Client();
    
    //This is fine
    (classToTest as any).containedClass.doSomethingInUnmockedBaseClass()
    //This is fine
    (classToTest as any).containedClass.somePublicField = MockClass.StaticReadonlyField
    
    //This test fails
    expect(classToTest.funcToTest()).toBeTruthy()

    //in Client.funcToTest()
    //if(this.containedClass.somePublicField === RealClass.StaticReadonlyField) {
    //  return true;
    //}
    //this.containedClass.somePublicField is properly set to 0
    //RealClass.StaticReadonlyField is undefined, RealClass is of type Function
  })
```

The test fails because `RealClass.StaticReadonlyField` is undefined within the context of the `Client` class. The question is, how do I define the static readonly fields of `RealClass` in `MockClass`, so that they are properly mocked inside of my `Client`?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421732/mocking-up-static-methods-in-jest . And make sure to clear or reset mocks in `beforeEach`